# Single linked lists & time complexity

Tags: c++, list, time-complexity

I'm trying to write my own (as close to standard as possible) single linked list implementation. However I am wondering what time complexity people expect of such a list?

Especially for inserting I am wondering how I should implement it. I've read some locations around the internet, where some say inserting is O(1) while others say O(n) - all agree that a double linked list is O(1). However I think O(1) is the case for single linked lists too?

As long as you know the preceding node you just let the preceding node point to the new new, and the new node will point towards where the preceding node did originally point to.

That said it makes me wonder how people expect `insert` to behave? Normally it inserts elements BEFORE the given iterator. However with a single-linked-list it is hard to do so (one would have to go through `O(n)` time to get the preceding element & then use above method). Is it common in such lists to make `insert` place items behind the current iterator? Or -probably better- is there another common function for this?

Comment: Inserting at the end and beginning is usually `O(1)`; in the middle it's `O(n)`. Perhaps your iterator could keep track of the preceding element in the linked list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [stl list - complexity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191790/stl-list-complexity)

Comment: @erisco I'm especially asking for places where `std::list` can't be the same as `std::forward_list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complexity of the insertion depends on what you need to do. If you know preceding node (actually, a suitable handle to change the preceding node's "next pointer" is all you need), the complexity is `O(1)`. If you need to find the location where to insert, the complexity is `O(n)`.

With respect to the expectation, I would expect the `insert()` to behave the same as for doubly linked lists but I also realize that you can't achieve this: You either need to have a different time complexity (to find the predecessor node) or different iterator invalidation semantics (i.e., iterators to other nodes get invalidated). I think the C++ 2011 `std::forward_list` class template went for a different interface but retaining the guarantees on iterator validity.

To briefly explain why the iterator validity can be effected: An iterator doesn't have to only know about the current node. Instead, it could, for example, point to the predecessor's `next` pointer. When dereferencing the iterator, it would dereference first its pointer to the `next` pointer and then this pointer to get hold of the actual node. In return, it is possible to insert in front of the iterator because the iterator knows which `next` pointer to update. Unfortunately, this means that iterators may get invalidated because the pointer they point to may have changed and they would reference a different node (when erasing nodes, the iterator may have been moved to be entirely invalid although the node referenced is still there).

Comment: The new C++11 container is [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list).

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Good point! I haven't implemented it, yet, so I keep forgetting its name. I'll update the response.